# Get text and image from pdf - Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, text, extract, pdf.js

Hi I am writing an application where I am parsing a pdf file and taking specific texts and creating a csv file out of it.

For this I am using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)!

I have written a filter method to extract text from **internalRenderTask.operatorList.argsArray** of the api.js (which is called when Render function is called). However I think there has to be a better way to fetch text and images directly using some method calls, so if you guys have used pdf.js methods or if there is any better way to do it, please suggest the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js or https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/text-only ?